# Better understanding of Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have read some theory based on Partial View, leaving me out with a few doubts. As I have read in some of the posts about Partial View in SO, I understand Partial View is a View that contains no Layout. Or a simplified version of a View that can be reused. For instance for a sidebar I could use Partial Views.

But I would like to know if I would like to render another View inside a View can Partial View be used? For instance I have a table with a list of items, I would like to display another table when one of the row in the parent table is clicked. Can the child table be represented using Partial View? Or do I need to look for something else to achieve the same?

Comment: Short answer is yes.

Comment: I should make a view for the parent table and a partial view for the child table, right?

Comment: Yes, and use ajax to call a method that returns the partial view when you click on the row.

Comment: OK. Thank you.. I will try it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences from reference http://completedevelopment.blogspot.in/2014/01/is-there-really-no-difference-between.html

The differences that were obvious from the code are

- Partial Views don't have a layout processed. Very important to know.
- Partial Views don't check for a _ViewStart.cshtml. Note this is typically where layouts are specified but technically you could specify one in your partial and it would be ignored. Very important to know.
- Partial Views can throw a slightly different exception, the details
  included to InvalidOperationException in PartialViewResult vs
  ViewResult classes. This is pretty minor.